# Maximum number of concave vertices in a polygon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let, $P$ be a closed polygon with $10$ sides and $10$ vertices. Let,$k$ be the number of interior angles of $P$ greater than $180^\circ$. Then the maximum value of $k$ is-

All I could make out is that the sum of all interior angles is $8\pi$. I have no idea how to proceed on this.

Thanks for any help. The result may please be generalised if possible.

Comment: You should at least be able to show quite easily that $7$ is possible, just by srawing.

Comment: @Arthur Okay... that's the correct answer but I did not find it so trivial ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In an $n$-gon, the total of the interior angles is $(n-2)\pi$. A concave angle is $>\pi$. There cannot be $n-2$ concave angles, as then the total of the angles would be $>(n-2)\pi$. But $n-3$ concave angles is possible, as demonstrated in this image (with $n=7$).

[image]

More rigorously, to show that $n-3$ is always possible: let $P_1=(1,1)$, and with $\theta=\frac{\pi}{n-2}$ $P_{2+k}=(\sin k\theta,\cos k\theta)$ for all $k=0,1,\dots,n-2$. Then the $n-3$ angles of polygon $P_1P_2\dots{}P_n$ at points $P_3,P_4,\dots,P_{n-1}$ are easily proven to be concave.

Comment: Thanks! But an you please make it a bit more rigorous?

Comment: @tatan I've made it a little more rigorous. Is that clear enough?

Comment: The diagram certainly proves the case where $n=10$, and the final paragraph is not needed for this specific case.  But I'm not actually convinced by the final paragraph in the general case.  Does the fact than a bunch of numbers add up to $\pi(n-2)$ necessarily imply that you can make a polygon with those numbers as its angles?  I don't think you've proved it.

Comment: But I'm not saying that; I provide a construction of the points, which demonstrates that it is possible.